# File Formatting and Parsing File to Excel in .NET

Tags: .net, file, excel, c#-4.0

We currently have a process whereby we write a pipe delimited (|) files. This file will contain different "LetterTemplateType". Each LetterTemplateType will have different fields and different # of fields.

To create the file, we put all the records in a Class and then call a method based on the LetterTemplateType:

```
private static void GenerateLetterTemplateTypeA(StringBuilder sb, 
                                                AALettersOutput output)
{
  if (sb == null) sb = new StringBuilder();

  sb.AppendLine();
  AddToString(sb, output.LetterTemplateType, true);
  AddToString(sb, output.RecordID, true);
  AddToString(sb, output.DealID, true);
```

etc...

So after the file is produced, we have often been asked to "Parse" the file and put it in excel. I've been doing this manually. There are different ways to do this like Interop.

My real question: How can I go about Producing a file and then Parsing a file and having the fields in 1 place? I don't want to have the field order in 2 different places in code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Excel Package Plus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) and produce xslx files pretty easy, here is the example code :

```
private void MakeExcelFile()
{
  ExcelPackage ePack = new ExcelPackage();
  ExcelWorksheet ws = ePack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Worksheet1");

  /// add 5 rows 
  ws.InsertRow(1, 5);
  /// excel cells and rows are 1 based index !
  for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
  {
    ws.Cells[i, 1].Value = "Row " + i.ToString() + ", Col 1";
    ws.Cells[i, 2].Value = "Row " + i.ToString() + ", Col 2";
    ws.Cells[i, 3].Value = "Row " + i.ToString() + ", Col 3";
  }

  ePack.SaveAs(new FileInfo("result.xlsx"));
}
```

Comment: The part of producing excel dodesn't have me concerned. I'm trying to produce a file and then later Parse and have the field names for each LetterTemplateType in 1 spot. I might have an idea...

Comment: What I actually need is a Dictionary but 2 fields for the lookup. So Name1+Name2 -> Value, LetterTemplateType+FieldName -> Position